# How to use Laravel blade custom function with the use view-passed variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Inside a partial for creating and editing form I had this to decide whether to display the current value (when editing) or an old value (when editing or creating and not passing the validator)

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="{{ old('title')?old('title'):$model->title }}">
```

This became a pain, so I created a custom blade function in app/helpers.php

```
function decide($inputName, $model){
    return old($inputName)?old($inputName):$model->$inputName;
}
```

This works well however, what I want to achieve is ultimately this

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="{{ decide('title') }}">
```

Without the need to pass in $model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Extending Blade`, which allows you to create your own custom blade function.

Read documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#extending-blade)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a default to `old`.

```
old('title', $model->title)
```

A null old value for title will use the default, no need for the ternary.

I don't know how you'd make the association without the model, however.